# Canvas Ball bounces in wrong direction when pong paddle is moving

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, canvas

I would like to start off with a note. I tried using a jsfiddle but for some reason HTML5 canvas does not work. So as a workaround I used http://jsbin.com/gugihuwegopa/1/. To edit with this site, click the edit button at the top right corner of the window. Anyway, my problem is, when the paddle is not moving, the ball bounces correctly off all sides (The `nomove` variable has nothing to do with that, its just to make it disappear with the "w" key). However, when I move the paddle with the mouse towards the ball, it gets stuck inside the paddle. I think this is because it is not updating the location of the paddle fast enough so that the ball ends up inside of it, and my code continues to cause the ball to bounce even while inside. (until moving the paddle rapidly away and it gets unstuck). Yes I have tried putting the `cxt.fillRect` before the `cxt.arc()`. Sometimes the ball will travel through the paddle as well. I figure a way to fix this would be factoring in the direction of the ball in my two `if` statements:

```
if(y+ymove>=w && y+ymove<=w+h && x>=s && x<=s+l ) ymove*=-1; //top and bottom
if(x+xmove>=s && x+xmove<=s+l && y+ymove<=w+h && y+ymove>=w ) xmove*=-1; //left and right
```

Some other methods I have tried include:

```
    if(y+ymove>=w && y+ymove<=w+h && x>=s && x<=s+l && centerY+17.5 < y+ymove+5 && centerX+12.5 < x+xmove+5) ymove*=-1; //top and bottom, extra +5 for radius
    if(x+xmove>=s && x+xmove<=s+l && y+ymove<=w+h && y+ymove>=w && centerX+12.5 < x+xmove+5 && centerY+17.5 < y+ymove+5) xmove*=-1; //left and right
```

So basically I just need the ball to bounce correctly no matter how I move the paddle. Feel free to edit all you want, even if it means adding more `if` statements. All I ask is absolutely  NO JQuery. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must think of collision handling as having (at least) two phases : Collision detection and Collision resolution. Here you solve the collision only by changing speed, but both objects might still intersect if one speed is very high : one object might well be inside the other : So you have also to solve position, or, if you prefer 'push' the ligthest object out of the heaviest.  You can do this by using a few min/max on the x,y,w,h of both objects.

OR, There's another 'dynamic' method to avoid object overlap : Have the collision handling time-driven. Split the collision handling into time sub-steps, making a stop on each collision. You must compute the time when the next collision will happen, then move everyone to that time, then update only the speeds, and do this again until enough time elapsed. So there not even a chance an overlap can happen : you 'stop the watch' on collision, then change speed, then restart time again. And several collision can happen in one frame, a case that won't be handled properly by a single-pass algorithm (case when a ball hit near a corner).
 An example : Say your game frame time, 'dt' is 16 ms, now you detect the ball hits paddle at 10.2ms -> you make both object moves for 10.2ms (x+=vx*10.2/y...), solve their speed (only), then you ask your collision engine to iterate a further 5.8ms.
It's a little work but i did it in my game engine, it works fine.

(Hope i've been more helping than confusing... :-) )

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do your code more friendly in order to get help, removing comments and keep only the parts you need to fix.

About your problem one thing you could do is to use a flag, if the ball is hitting the paddle set the flag to True, do the redirection once and stop checking for the collision until the flag is false.

For sure there should be a better workaround but that's a start.